# summation of a binomial expression that doesn't start from 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following expression:

$$
\sum_{k=9}^{17}\binom{17}{k}
$$
and I need to show that it's equal to:
$$
2^{16}
$$
now I know that if 'k' was starting from zero and not from 9 , like this:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}
$$
then there is this identity that says it's equal to:
$$
2^{17}
$$
But Because the summation starts from 9 I don't know what to do..
can you help please?
thank you

Answer (score 10):

For integers $n, k$ with $0 \le k \le n$, the binomial coefficients satisfy
the “symmetry”
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}
$$

It follows that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{17}{k}  =
\sum_{k=9}^{17}\binom{17}{17-k}  =
 \sum_{k=9}^{17}\binom{17}{k}
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{k=9}^{17}\binom{17}{k} = \frac 12 \sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}
= \frac 12 \cdot (1+1)^{17} = 2^{16} \, .
$$

But note that this approach works only in this symmetric case where
we sum the first or second half of the binomial coefficients in a
row of Pascal's triangle for odd $n$ (or with a small modification
for even $n$).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums),
there is no closed formula for the general case $\sum_{k=j}^n \binom nk$
unless one resorts to the Hypergeometric function.

Comment: I don't understand why: $$
\sum_{k=9}^{17}\binom{17}{k} = 
0.5 * \sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}
$$

Comment: @Noam: See expanded answer.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. Thank you very much @Martin R

Comment: @Noam: You are welcome! – Remark: You got some answers to your questions now. Please don't forget to *accept* helpful answers eventually. For each of your questions, try to choose one answer and accept it by clicking on the *check mark*. That marks the problem as closed and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k} -\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{17}{k}= 2^{17} - 2^{16}$$

$$  =2^{16}(2-1)= 2^{16}$$